# Generate an almost flat world in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-worldedit

I had started a "builds" world (default world settings) in 1.12.2 some time ago and am adding new builds weekly, hence I decided to make the map like a big city, divided in areas by architectural style.

### The Problem

The problem is terrain. I've tried to flatten it with WorldEdit (I have chosen my base level to be 63), but it leaves awful walls at the edges: [image: Edges left after utilisng WorldEdit]
And WorldEdit's `//smooth` does a terrible job covering them (as seen bellow).
[image: WorldEdit's "smooth" tool is useless]
*(thank you WE for the stairs)*

### What I've tried

#### 1. World type: customised

I have tried playing around with the preset settings using [this online tool (minecraft.tools)](https://minecraft.tools/en/custom.php?preset=0) and most specifically with the "micro-relief" setting (I used low values).
This did a great job in matters of flatness, but did some huge malformations with mountains (without touching anything else than micro-relief):
[image: mountain malformations]
These caves beneath are gigantic (600+ blocks), super common and sometimes even stacked vertically (as the ones in the upper part of the picture). Extremely steep cliffs are also not a rare sight. (On the bottom right you can see a piece of nice and flat plains).

#### 2. World type: super flat (preset with decorations - ores, trees, etc.)

This is now way too flat. No rivers, hills, no *regular* mountains. It doesn't look natural.

### What would be the perfect result?

Mountains and rivers (as a background/panorama) surrounding some big flat areas (plains, forests, etc.) with minimum elevation difference.
If possible, I'm looking for some **advice or tips** on how to generate a world that is a combination of the two images below:

**Default World** (as a background to the scenery)
[image: default world screenshot]

**World with low values of "micro-relief"** (land to build big mansions, houses, and cities)
[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you are not adverse to using tools to edit the world outside of the game, [WorldPainter](https://www.worldpainter.net) may help you solve what you are after.

It is a self described map generator which "allows you to "paint" landscapes using similar tools as a regular paint program." which if you have not started building yet could help you flatten the landscape with what is essentially 3D painting tools for Minecraft.

I'm not currently in a location where I can test this program out myself, but it is worth a try. It's free, Open-Source and uses GPL. I've seen maps created with WorldPainter before, and if it allows you to create landscapes like this: [image]

Then flattening terrain should be a breeze. As the saying goes, if you want something done right, do it yourself (With the best tools you can get)

Comment: This looks interesting. I will try it when I have the time

Answer (score 2):

There's no simple vanilla way to generate a world that I know of, that has a specific biome layout like a huge plain in the center and hills/mountains around - the best you can do is generate a 'large biomes' world, use a tool like AMIDST to find as big a plains biome as possible, then set world spawn there.

An easier option, that will unfortunately not provide the nice background mountains, is to generate a buffet world of nothing but plains:

[image]

The terrain is mostly flat, with occasional small hills, and the entire world is covered by this biome. To achieve this, pick Create New World, More World Options..., World Type: Buffet, Customize, Plains. Or Sunflower Plains, for extra sunflowers.

[image]

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that even though the plains biome features minimum elevation, it is still enough to cause 6-block-tall walls when made flat. I could try to create a plains world with low micro-relief (so it's mainly flat) and try copy/paste some mountains using WorldEdit

Comment: @user10398534: I don't think there's a vanilla way to generate such terrain (maybe other than custom worldgen implemented as hundreds of command blocks). Maybe there are mods, but I don't know them.